# ¡Como soluciono ese error? Ya no se que mas hacer

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int op = 0;
    float A = 1.5, B= 2.7, C = 3.9, titi;
    cout << "Bienvenido a mi menu ;)" << endl;
    cout << "1 Ejecutar el primer programa" << endl;
    cout << "2. Ejecutar el segundo programa" << endl;
    cout << "4.¡Salir!"<< endl;
    cin >> op;
    
   switch(op){
       case 1:
            int capital;
            int ganancia;
            int nueva_ganancia;
            cout << "Ingrese capital a invertir: ";
            cin >> capital;
            ganancia = capital * 1.9 / 100;
            nueva_ganancia = capital + ganancia;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12); i++); >> me causa un error en esta parte //error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope  // error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token   
            cout << "la ganancia por el capital invertido es: "<< ganancia <<endl;
            cout <<"la ganacia con el capital invertido es: " << nueva_ganancia<<endl; break;
            
       case 2: 
            titi = A;
            A = B;
            B = C;
            C = titi;
            cout << A << " " << B << " " << C << endl; break;
            
       case 3: break;
   }
```

Comment: Por favor escribe bien tu pregunta. Así como está es confusa y difícil de leer. Lo que si puedo ver es que tienes un `)` antes del `;` en el for.

Comment: El `for` esta mal

Comment: Como dicen los comentarios de arriba el `for` está mal, intenta hacer esto: `for(int i=0;i<=12;i++);`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas en el código:

**Paréntesis dentro del bucle**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12); i++);
//                     ^
```

Ese paréntesis sobra. El bucle debería quedar así

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++);
```

El bucle ahora ya sí compilaría pero... no va a hacer nada. El motivo es que has terminado el bucle con punto y coma

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++);
//                           ^
```

Eso hace que el bucle no vaya a ejecutar ninguna línea de código adicional. Como además el bucle únicamente actualiza la variable `i`, que únicamente existe dentro del bucle ... pues eso, este bucle tal y como está no hace nada productivo. Quizás debas meter el cálculo de la ganancia dentro de este bucle

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
   // Calculo de ganancias mes a mes
}
```

**No hay decimales**

Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que los cálculos no los estás haciendo correctamente. Todas las variables involucradas son de tipo entero, un tipo de dato que no admite decimales. Esto quiere decir que tu programa no está dando resultados correctos

**Variables dentro del switch**

La estructura de control `switch-case` no funciona exactamente igual que los bucles o los condicionales. Esta estructura no crea ningún ámbito, por lo que las variables que declares en los `case` estarán declaradas, en este caso, a nivel de la función. Esto es un problema, ya que si te equivocas y usas una de las funciones declaradas en un `case` en otro `case` distinto lo que sucede entonces es que accederás a posiciones de memoria no inicializadas y no te iba a gustar el resultado.

Para declarar variables en un `case` tienes que usar llaves dentro del `case`:

```
case 1:
{
    int capital;
    int ganancia;
    int nueva_ganancia;
    cout << "Ingrese capital a invertir: ";
    cin >> capital;
    ganancia = capital * 1.9 / 100;
    nueva_ganancia = capital + ganancia;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12); i++); >> me causa un error en esta parte //error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope  // error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token   
    cout << "la ganancia por el capital invertido es: "<< ganancia <<endl;
    cout <<"la ganacia con el capital invertido es: " << nueva_ganancia<<endl; break;
}
```

**Declara los break en una línea nueva**

C++  es un lenguaje compilado. Esto quiere decir que el tamaño del programa final, así como sus tiempos de ejecución, no se van a ver influídos por saltos de línea, tabuladores o espacios que se encuentren en el código.

Es decir, no vas a ganar nada al compactar las líneas y, sin embargo, si vas a complicar la legibilidad del código.

C++ ya es suficientemente complicado de usar como para encima ir poniendo trampas en el código.

Mueve los `break` a una línea independiente y tu código será más facil de entender

```
case 1:
{
    int capital;
    int ganancia;
    int nueva_ganancia;
    cout << "Ingrese capital a invertir: ";
    cin >> capital;
    ganancia = capital * 1.9 / 100;
    nueva_ganancia = capital + ganancia;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++); 
    cout << "la ganancia por el capital invertido es: "<< ganancia <<endl;
    cout <<"la ganacia con el capital invertido es: " << nueva_ganancia<<endl;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes un paréntesis de más en el bucle, detrás de la condición, elimínalo y te debería funcionar correctamente.
for(int i =0; i<=n;i++)

Espero que te sirva, un saludo

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).